# Pyspark cogroup rdd

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm new to pyspark and after 2 days of searching, I'm still don't understand what I'm doing wrong with cogroup.
This is what want to do:
I got a text file with a lot of words and each word has a value:

```
Hello 5
  .
  .
  .
Hi    8
Ops   9
```

and I got another file that contains sentences
`Hello my name is name`
I want to calculate the value of the whole sentences according to the first file.
As you can see in the code I turned the first file to rdd that's looks like this:
`[(Hi,8),...(Ops,9)]`
For the second file I want to create rdd that looks like that:
`[(Hello,1),...(Name,2)]`
now when im trying to cogroup im getting this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-c424da6be07f> in <module>
      2 lines = ssc.textFileStream(dataDirectory)
      3 
----> 4 counts = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")) \
      5    .map(lambda x: (x, 1)) \
      6    .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b) \

/usr/local/spark/spark/python/pyspark/streaming/dstream.py in cogroup(self, other, numPartitions)
    350         if numPartitions is None:
    351             numPartitions = self._sc.defaultParallelism
--> 352         return self.transformWith(lambda a, b: a.cogroup(b, numPartitions), other)
    353 
    354     def join(self, other, numPartitions=None):

/usr/local/spark/spark/python/pyspark/streaming/dstream.py in transformWith(self, func, other, keepSerializer)
    313         jfunc = TransformFunction(self._sc, func, self._jrdd_deserializer, other._jrdd_deserializer)
    314         dstream = self._sc._jvm.PythonTransformed2DStream(self._jdstream.dstream(),
--> 315                                                           other._jdstream.dstream(), jfunc)
    316         jrdd_serializer = self._jrdd_deserializer if keepSerializer else self._sc.serializer
    317         return DStream(dstream.asJavaDStream(), self._ssc, jrdd_serializer)

AttributeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute '_jdstream'
```

This is my code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext 

# Create Streaming Context with batch interval of 5 second. 
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 5)
# creating rdd for all the words in the dictionary file
text_file = sc.textFile('AFINN-111.txt')
def createPair(line):
    x = line.replace("\t"," ").split(" ")
    return (x[0],int(x[1]))
        
dictionary = text_file.map(createPair)
print(dictionary.take(20))
                         dataDirectory = 'FILES'
lines = ssc.textFileStream(dataDirectory) 

counts = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")) \
   .map(lambda x: (x, 1)) \
   .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b) \
   .cogroup(dictionary)
    
    

counts.pprint()
# Start the computation
ssc.start() 
ssc.awaitTermination()
```